# GrabURL from Website table

Tags: android, url, fetch

Hi Guys I Want to Grab an URL from a site the page only has one or many URL link on it, I would like to connect to the site URL and grab the link fro inside the page And put that in a string, Can It be done? I want to do it in android. Excuse me If this is a simple question Is that I really don't know how to do it, I have done researched but I am confused.

I want to grab this page 
http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win64/last/

It's Vlc, There are 6 Links and they are constantly updated, How can I get the urls and put them each on a string on My activity?, I want to fetch the links when the app is loaded so It gets the links as they are changing from day to day.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need an HTML Parser like JSoup: http://jsoup.org/.

Comment: I know JSOUP but It doesn't seem to work right here, It crashes the app and doesn't return any value to the string, It's Blank